# Are questions about devices such as the new Commodore 64 Mini on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Title says it all. Are questions about devices such as the new [Commodore 64 Mini](https://thec64.com) on topic here?

It seems like an interesting device, but mainly seems to be a C-64 emulator running on an ARM chip. And while the keyboard is there for aesthetics (ie: doesn’t work) one can hook up a basic USB keyboard to simplify keyboard data entry.

Since there are supposedly thousands of users still programming for the C-64 and—I assume—emulation plays some role in their workflow, would a dedicated hardware emulator like this be an on-topic subject here?

For example, [SID](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/SID) programming is a thing for many C-64 enthusiasts. If I were to somehow start SID programming through the BASIC emulator on a Commodore 64 Mini, would it make sense for me to point out I am using such a device rather than a real C-64?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why not. We've had questions about software emulators and they've been well received. Questions about technicalities about the machine (like flashing it to do other things) wouldn't be on-topic, since it's only in scope as an emulator, but most questions would be fine.

Comment: Well put.  To that end, I would suggest that questions like https://superuser.com/q/1343016/247927 would be off-topic as they are not about emulating retro machines but are about the modern architecture.

Comment: @Chenmunka Good to know.

Comment: @Chenmunka Too bad, that link no longer works. Do you got a copy, or could you tell about it's content.

Comment: @Raffzahn What CPU architecture is in the Commodore C64 mini?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 AFAIK it's build with an Allwinner A20 SoC, which includes a dual core ARM Cortex A7 running Linux at ~1 GHz,including virtualizazion, a Mali GPU. Basicly is like a Bananna Pi in a C64 lookalike shell. The 8 bit Guy shows (an early) board in his review starting at minute 20: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXXCj5kqPcM

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Here isa close up of the board: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3nas70YsEcE - it's effectivly just the A20, 256 MiB RAM, 256 MiB Flash and a system/power controller. So it's even less than a Banana Pi hardware wise.

Comment: @Raffzahn No, that's the title of the question... Sorry; I meant to add more content to the comment but forgot after uncovering that tidbit from my internet history.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Now I'm thruout confused :S

Comment: @Raffzahn "Too bad, that link no longer works. Do you got a copy, or could you tell about it's content." I found the title.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not realy sure why it should be on topic. It's a new hardware with a new software and just because it got put in a case that reminds of a C64, doesn't make a difference.

If we would accept it as on topic **per se** than we need to accept any modern hardware with any modern software as soon as some marketing guy puts a retro label on the box.

Having said that, there still *may* be questions that are RC related. For example when someone is trying to write programs *within* the original (i.e. emulated) environment, his questions could quite well fit RC, as there is no relevant difference between using this and the classic environment. I would like to call this *'Equivalent Questions'* as the very same question could also come up with the original hard/software.

Another on topic issue may be hardware questions related to a potential use of old hardware with the new one (like an original 1541 with the mini-C64). At least for most of them. In fact, due the use of old hardware it's direct on-topic.

In contrast, a question of how the print-screen key of a PC keyboard connected works is clearly off-topic (just trying to make a case). Similar about configuration or management of the emulation software.

Keep in mind, RC is neiter a superuser/How-To for modern hardware nor classic.